# Combining two assembly files together with both text and data section

Tags: gcc, assembly, arm

I have two assembly files, a.s and b.s
I want to combine both of them and create a new assembly file c.s
The file c.s should have all the code in .text of a.s and then all then code in .text of b.s
I want to do the same thing with .data section

```
# File a.s
VSUB.F32 S4, S5, S6
.data
.word 0x10000000

# File b.s
VADD.F32 S4, S5, S6
.data
.word 0x20000000

# File c.s
.include "a.s"
.include "b.s"
```

I want my output to look like this:

```
.text
VSUB.F32 S4, S5, S6
VADD.F32 S4, S5, S6

.data
.word 0x10000000
.word 0x20000000
```

However, this is what I see after dumping the object file.

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
0:  ee322ac3    vsub.f32    s4, s5, s6


00000000 <.data>:
0:  10000000    .word   0x10000000
4:  ee710a21    vadd.f32    s1, s2, s3
8:  20000000    .word   0x20000000
```

Comment: Note that your solution would actually work if you switched back to the `.text` section before emitting code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thats exactly what a linker does what is the problem?

a.s

```
add r0,r0,r0

.data

aaa: .word 0xAAAAAAAA
```

b.s

```
add r1,r1,r1

.data

bbbb: .word 0xBBBBBBBB
```

build:

```
arm-none-eabi-as a.s -o a.o
arm-none-eabi-as b.s -o b.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -Ttext=0x1000 -Tdata=0x2000 a.o b.o -o ab.elf
arm-none-eabi-ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000001000
```

disassemble:

```
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D ab.elf

Disassembly of section .text:

00001000 <.text>:
    1000:   e0800000    add r0, r0, r0
    1004:   e0811001    add r1, r1, r1

Disassembly of section .data:

00002000 <__data_start>:
    2000:   aaaaaaaa    bge feaacab0 <_stack+0xfea2cab0>

00002004 <bbbb>:
    2004:   bbbbbbbb    bllt    feef0ef8 <_stack+0xfee70ef8>
```

completely useless code but its that simple.  You can then complicate it more by using a linker script, etc.

Naturally the code needs to make sense it wants to branch or call functions locally or in other objects with a sane flow.  But it is easy to see with this example that the linker simply put the .text sections together and the .data sections together.

Unless dictated by a linker script the order they land in the output so far as I have seen is determined by the order found on the linker command line.

Answer (score 1):

Add `.text` to the beginning of each file.

The assembler starts with the section set to `.text`.  However, when you use `.include`, it is in the context of the including file (*c.s* in your case) which has the section set to `.data` from the previous include.

Theoretically, you only have to add a `.text` to the top of the *b.s* source, but it is always good practice to just always use a `.text` declaration at the start of your asembler file.  You might like `.unified`, `.thumb`, etc.

It is true that a linker will solve this issue, but a common practical case is mixing generated assembler with custom code.  Generally, you just need *driver.s* to include *generated.s* and don't need the third file.  The generated file is typical a table or data structure from another source such as 'C' structure offsets, conversion constants, etc.